# get image from laravel and display it in flutter

Tags: laravel, flutter, image, get, dio

i got an error
**Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///jsonlist%5Bindex%5D%5B'image'%5D **and **Leading widget consumes entire tile width. Please use a sized widget, or consider replacing ListTile with a custom widget**

```
LARAVEL 
code for get data from database dan sent those to flutter

public function getData(){
        $images=imageModel::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
        return response()->json($images);
       
}
```

```
FLUTTER
and this is my code in flutter


  void getData() async{
    try{
    var response =await Dio().get("http://192.168.1.10:80/api/getdata");
    // print(response.data);//i try to print the response and those successed recieved by flutter
    if(response.statusCode==200){
      setState(() {
        jsonlist=response.data as List;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
        return Card(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80),
              child: Image.network(jsonlist[index]['image'],fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,width: 50,height: 50,),
            ),
            title: Text(jsonlist[index]['title']),

          ),
        );
      },
        itemCount: jsonlist==null ? 0:jsonlist.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

with those codes above the data's has sent it to flutter but it didnt work displayed the image in listile,
could anybody help me... how to display the images?

Comment: can i see the response in postman?

Comment: {
        "id": 15,
        "title": "Batagor",
        "image": "post/bF3uVXyJYhJKw6qxCY3j45inp6r0KnCHfEkh2Tux.jpg",
        "created_at": "2023-06-05T13:55:38.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-06-05T13:55:38.000000Z"
    },

ini mas..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right but when you pass the image URL to `Image.network()` you need to remove the double quotes.

```
 Image.network(jsonlist[index]['image'].toString(),
  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
  width: 50, 
  height: 50,
),
```

try with this

Comment: it's still error. and the error still same
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///post/6YGT7AeP8AzvDCGjADb57GmKfK5WZ9u2qo6dsinC.jpg